# lodash/underscore - using bind with method call and method remains unbound

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, this, lodash

Here is the relevant code:

```
    render: function(args, callback) {

        connectorPromise = ConnectorDelegate.currentConnectors();
        iconPromise = connectorUtils.getIconList();
        // when promises resolve call method and bind it to "this"

        $.when(connectorPromise, iconPromise).then(_.bind(this.createConnectorCollection), this);
    },

    createConnectorCollection: function(connectors, iconList) {
       // This is the window object in here
    }...
```

Inside the render method "this" is correctly bound.  When I call the createConnectorCollection method however "this" becomes the window object.  How do I correctly bind this to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your closing parentheses is misplaced:

```
$.when(connectorPromise, iconPromise).then(_.bind(this.createConnectorCollection, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the context as a second parameter to `bind`, not to `then` method.

It worth to mention that `underscore` is not requires as you can use [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `bind` method:

```
this.createConnectorCollection.bind(this)
```